# Wireless radio reception power vs distance

Tags: wireless, distance

I found a PDF online that says:

> The diagram shows that one unit of power is required to achieve a given data rate over one unit of distance. But to maintain the same data rate over x the distance, a traditional wireless network requires not x but rather 16x the power.

It refers to this diagram:

[image: RX power vs distance]

Shouldn't it have been 9X the power (instead of 16X) or 4X the distance (instead of 3X)?

Comment: calculate the surface area of a sphere that has a radius of 1 meter, then calculate the same for a radius of 2m and 3m .... what is the ratio of areas?

Comment: It all depends on what link loss formula they assumed. Does the pdf tell you that?

Comment: @Andyaka they didn't

Comment: Can you link the pdf please

Comment: http://www.motorola.com/innovators/pdfs/mesh-ntwks-wp-7.24.06.pdf

Comment: @jsotola for 3m it's 9X times the surface area of 1m

Comment: @LuísMarques, i was not thinking clearly. somehow i thought "area" and my brain thought "volume" and my fingers typed a stupid comment ... lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How they modelled the path loss is key to how they came up with 16x the power: -

[image]

[Slideshow here](http://slideplayer.com/slide/5284584/).

In free space, the exponent is 2 and this means that for 3 times the transmit distance you will need 9x the power.

But, conceivably they could have used an exponent of 2.53 and \$3^{2.53}\$ = 16.1.

Personally I think the marketing guys have messed-up because this is known to happen.

Comment: I like the understatement of the last sentence :)

Comment: Marketing guys (and politicians) have a great talent for making things so simple that they are basically useless. So, 9m or 16m is just alternative facts ;-)